# angularjs tree from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking to use the example http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/index.html to build several trees.

Right now, I can't seem to decide the best method of posting a multidimensional array into the tree from $http.get.

I am certain it would have something to do with what's below, but from there I am not sure.

```js
$scope.tree1 = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "tree1 - item1",
      "nodes": [],
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "tree1 - item2",
      "nodes": [],
    }
    /* more tree nodes */
]
```

Any help would be great...

Cheers

Comment: could you paste the HTML that you're using with the ui-tree directives?

Comment: When you say "posting a multidimensional array into the tree from $http.get", do you really mean to display tree on the page?